# Windows Form IsClosing flag?

Tags: winforms

Is there a way to know if a Windows Form is closing?

I would have to know from another class with a reference to the windows form. Something like:

if WinForm.IsClosing then ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using the event [Form.FormClosing Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx)

> The FormClosing event occurs as the form is being closed. When a form
>   is closed, it is disposed, releasing all resources associated with the
>   form. If you cancel this event, the form remains opened. To cancel the
>   closure of a form, set the Cancel property of the FormClosingEventArgs
>   passed to your event handler to true.

Comment: Well, yeah, I knew I had to be more specific. It's no option to do it with the event. I have to know from another instance with a reference to the WinForm if it is closing. Now I have an extra property in the WinForm class (boolean IsClosing), but I wanted to know if there's something in WinForms similar to that.

Comment: Weird, it should work with the event. Why not? If you do it property based, instead of event-based, you'll have the risk to just miss the event. The form will be already close after you try to evaluate the "IsClosing" flag.